# ASP MVC 4 - diagram tools

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, diagram

I am looking for the best way to implement a real time diagram tool to use in my website. I've found a website with something similar: mentionmapp.com .. You can see the diagram on the background of the homepage, if any can give me suggestions to create something similar I'd appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than a .NET solution, why not look at a JavaScript solution (with data fed in via JSON) as these are much more common.

http://arborjs.org/ is one I've used before and pretty popular (and free!).

There are .NET components you could use (like http://www.devcomponents.com/treegx/) but you'll have to pay for them.

Comment: arbor.js looks like a fantastic option, thank you!