# How to generate a diagram of all services in a C# Visual Studio 2012 MVC 4 Web Application (Using VS2013)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, model-view-controller, get

I have created a project of type Visual C# -> Web -> Visual Studio 2012 -> ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application.

In this project are MODELS and CONTROLLERS.  The CONTROLLERS house GETs and POSTs functions, each with their own unique parameters/payload expectations.

I would like to visualize the SERVICES in the project via a diagram or some other interactive tool, but do not know if this is possible, and what tools to use if it is possible.

If i have worded anything wrong, or am missing some buzzwords/keywords that would help me utilize google further, please let me know, and potentially, I could close the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176102/asp-mvc-4-diagram-tools

Comment: @pankajparkar worst reference ever.